# Can I use waitForElementWidth Selenium command independently

Tags: testing, selenium, selenium-ide

I just started playing with Selenium and I ran into an issue. I have a link that toggles a hidden div into view using a scroll transition. I am trying to test this function using selenium and the following steps:

1.click on toggle button
2.wait for open transition to finish
3.click on toggle button again to close

My question is can i use waitForElementWidth command for step number 2 without first storing my width with storeElementWidth? lets say I already know the final width of the div when viewable is 200px. Can i do something like:

command: waitForElementWidth
target: id=mydiv
value: 200

It seems to fail for some reason.

EDIT: I am aware that I can use the Pause command with the amount of time that the transition is set for but I am trying to stay away from set times which might change later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found the answer to this is yes you can use it independently. What i was doing wrong is that I was entering the value as a string in quotations when i just needed to enter it as simple value.